# emacs projectile: how to add multiple folders to project (like vscode)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emacs, emacs-projectile

I am new to emacs, coming from VSCode, trying to setup projectile. So far my configuration includes:

```
(use-package projectile
 :ensure t
 :diminish projectile-mode
 :config (projectile-mode)
 :custom ((projectile-completion-system 'helm))
 :bind-keymap
 ("C-c p" . projectile-command-map)
 :init
 (when (file-directory-p "/home/user/code")
   (setq projectile-project-search-path '("/home/user/code"))))
```

One of the things I loved in VSCode is the ability to create .code-workspace files. Within such a file, I could specify multiple directories that would be included in my workspace.
The projectile notion of a project (https://docs.projectile.mx/projectile/projects.html) seems to always associate a project with one root directory.

Is there any way in which I could use multiple root directories in a project? Could the .projectile file accomplish the same as the .code-workspace file?